# Testing reference equality on a recursive array

Tags: php, reference

```
<?php
$a = [];
$b = [&$a];
$a[] = &$b;
```

Assuming we have a recursive array - is there any PHP builtin that will test for equality including references?

Standard comparison operators throw a fatal error, and while `array_diff` doesn't crash it does spit out a ton of notices.

I could always compare `print_r($a, true) == print_r($b, true)` but this would incorrectly identify `$a` and `$b` as the same (Their values may be the same but the references they contain aren't)

Comment: unless they've added it in php7, there's no way to access details about the referencing mechanism, and there's no way to spot if two different vars are references to the same thing.

Comment: Well you can check if they're references to the same thing by *changing* it but that doesn't really help my use case. Oh well

Comment: well, you can always have references to references. that means, `$x = 7, $y = &$x; $z = &$y`, so $z will change when $x does, but since z is a reference to y, they're not quite the same thing.

Comment: "but that doesn't really help my use case" What is your use case again?